# Python socket non-blocking recv() exception(s) and sendall() exception

Tags: python, sockets, exception, nonblocking

I'm writing a simple TCP relay server, which is gonna be deployed both on a Windows and a Linux machine (same code base).
Naturally there're gonna be two sockets to work with.
I would like to know which exceptions exactly do get raised for the following cases:

1. `recv()` returns when no data is available to read.
2. `sendall()` cannot complete (dispose of the whole to-send data)

- Do I have to check for both errnos (`socket.EWOULDBLOCK` and `socket.EAGAIN`) when expecting to return from a non-blocking sockets `recv()`?
- Which `errno` (`.args[0]`) do I get when `sendall()` fails?

Here's my code so far:

```
try:
    socket1.setblocking(False)
    socket2.setblocking(False)

    while True:
        try:
            sock1_data = socket1.recv(1024)
            if sock1_data:
                socket2.sendall(sock1_data)
        except socket.error as e:
            if e.args[0] != socket.EAGAIN and e.args[0] != socket.EWOULDBLOCK:
                raise e

        try:
            sock2_data = socket2.recv(1024)
            if sock2_data:
                socket1.sendall(sock2_data)
        except socket.error as e:
            if e.args[0] != socket.EAGAIN and e.args[0] != socket.EWOULDBLOCK:
                raise e
except:
    pass
finally:
    if socket2:
        socket2.close()
    if socket1:
        socket1.close()
```

My main concern is:
What `socket.error.errno` do I get when `sendall()` fails?

Lest the `socket.error.errno` I get from a failing `sendall()` is `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`, in which case it'd be troubling!!

Also, do I have to check for both `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` when handling a non-blocking `recv()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A Deep Dive

In CPython, `socket.sendall` is implemented by [sock_sendall](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/socketmodule.c#L4335) in socketmodule.c, which calls [sock_send_impl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/socketmodule.c#L4282) indirectly via [sock_call_ex](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/socketmodule.c#L845) (as does `socket.send` too). Ultimately, this results in calling the system call `send(...)`, which will set errno accordingly. `sock_call_ex` will handle some of the potential errors- it may automatically retry on `EINTR`, and for `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN` it will retry if there's a positive timeout.

Apart from that, however, `socket.sendall` can by and large produce most of the same errors that `send` can. There are a few, related to malformed arguments that should be impossible, assuming no bugs in python's socket module implementation, but the rest are valid, including `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK`. You can consult the man pages for a list of errors that `send` can produce, or [see this online list](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html#ERRORS).

As for `socket.recv`, the implementation is at [sock_recv_impl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/socketmodule.c#L3605), which calls `recv` directly, resulting in a similar situation. Again, see the man pages, or [online](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html#ERRORS).

In short, for `recv()`, you indeed need to handle both `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` for no data available, unless you know your platform so you can determine which it will raise. For `sendall()`, the errors you need to handle will depend on the errors you want to support / recover from. As an extreme example- you could get `ENOMEM` if you ran out of memory as it tries to fulfill the send request, however that's an extremely unlikely scenario, and you would already have bigger problems at that point.

#### XY Problem

Luckily, in your case there's an easy solution, since you're really just concerned with distinguishing the expected errors on nonblocking recv from actual errors during either recv or send. Just move the `socket.sendall` out of the `try` body, using the `else` construct:

```py
while True:
    try:
        sock1_data = socket1.recv(1024)
    except socket.error as e:
        if e.args[0] != socket.EAGAIN and e.args[0] != socket.EWOULDBLOCK:
            raise e
    else:  # only runs if there was no exception
        if sock1_data:
            socket2.sendall(sock1_data)

    try:
        sock2_data = socket2.recv(1024)
    except socket.error as e:
        if e.args[0] != socket.EAGAIN and e.args[0] != socket.EWOULDBLOCK:
            raise e
    else:  # only runs if there was no exception
        if sock2_data:
            socket1.sendall(sock2_data)
```